# border-image overflowing % based grid system

Tags: html, css

I'm using a grid system that uses percents (the [1140px grid](http://cssgrid.net) to be precise) and trying to use CSS3 border-images on it. It all works correctly, but I'm using some fairly wide fancy borders which are throwing off the width of the box. Is there any way to fix this? (or to do a way to do some fancy css borders without the CSS3? I'd love that, but can't find how and am failing at the moment.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add the following to the box's CSS

```
box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
```

Then it will add bordes inside the defined width rather than outside.

Comment: Works in the latest version of every browser including IE 8 and 9.